# Find element locator on IE webddriver (Any driver actually)

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

This post is to share a solution I've built to help find elements on webdrivers using System.in, since there are no (at least that I'm aware of) extensions to find locators on IE.

This solution is not ideal and may present issues, however, you can easily implement navigations and it gives you a quick response/highlight the elements.

Package:

```
package locator;
```

Imports:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
```

Class:

```
public class LocatorHelper {
private static WebDriver driver = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    createIE();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com.br/");
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String mainXpath = "";
    String lastXpath = "";

    while (!mainXpath.equals("exit")) {
        System.out.println("Type an xpath: ");
        lastXpath = mainXpath;
        mainXpath = scan.nextLine();
        if (lastXpath.length() > 0) {
            List<WebElement> elements = getElements(lastXpath, true);
            if (elements != null) {
                for (WebElement element : elements) {
                    js.executeScript("arguments[0].style.border='1px solid orange'", element);
                }
            }
        }
        List<WebElement> elements = getElements(mainXpath);
        if (elements != null) {
            for (WebElement element : elements) {
                js.executeScript("arguments[0].style.border='3px solid red'", element);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    }
}

private static List<WebElement> getElements(String xpath, boolean... disableLog) {
    List<WebElement> elements = null;
    try {
        elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpath));
        int count = elements.size();
        if (disableLog.length == 0) {
            if (count > 1) {
                System.out.println("The xpath '" + xpath + "' returned " + count + " elements");
            } else if (count == 1) {
                System.out.println("The xpath '" + xpath + "' returned one element");
            } else {
                System.out.println("The xpath '" + xpath + "' returned no elements");
            }
        }
    } catch (InvalidSelectorException e) {
        if (disableLog.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("The xpath '" + xpath + "' is not valid");
        }
    }
    return elements;
}

private static void createIE() {
    //your driver locator
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "src/main/resources/drivers/IEDriverServerNew.exe");
    DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
    caps.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);
    caps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
    caps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.ELEMENT_SCROLL_BEHAVIOR, true);
    DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer().setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);
    caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
    caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.SUPPORTS_JAVASCRIPT, true);
    caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);

    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(caps);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
}
}
```

In this image, the locator found a single element
[Example of a single element located](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vf54.png)

In this image, the locator found 20 elements
[Example of 20 elements found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNBE2.png)

As you type the locators on the terminal, it will highlight the current elements in red and all previous elements found will be highlighted in orange with a thinner line.

[Example of input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btIIO.png)

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution here. You could post it as an answer and mark it as an accepted answer after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: An easier way would be to use Chrome or Firefox for extracting XPaths.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question. It is a blog post that belongs elsewhere.

Comment: The aim of the solution is to cover applications made exclusively for IE, and it's not a question indeed, but I couldn't find a better place to post it here, if someone knows it I would be glad to know

Comment: @FelipeAmorim That’s rather the point. This doesn’t belong on StackOverflow at all. It belongs on your personal blog. If you don’t have one, there are dozens of free services that will let you create one. I appreciate that you have a solution you want to share with the widest audience possible, but StackOverflow (a Q&A site) isn’t the place for this type of post.